# Problems in implementing an iterator class

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a class named `MainControl`, and another one name `Participant`.

One of the parameters of `MainControl` is an array that contains pointers to objects from the class `Participant`.

Now, I am required to implement an iterator that will be able to run this code properly (any changes are not allowed):

```
 MainControl::Iterator i;
 for (i = eurovision.begin(); i<eurovision.end(); ++i)
 cout << *i << endl;
```

From this I understand that I need to create an `Iterator` class within the `MainControl` class.

I defined the `Iterator` class like this:

```
class Iterator {
        Participant* address;
    public:
        Iterator(): address(NULL){
        }
        explicit Iterator(Participant* p_participant) : address(p_participant) {
        }
        bool operator==(const Iterator& i) const;
        bool operator<(const Iterator& i) const;
        Iterator& operator++();
        Participant& operator*();
        const Participant& operator*() const; 
    };
```

One of the problems that I am facing is that I am not sure how to properly overload the `<` and `++` operators.

The array of the pointers to the participants is defined as a private field in the class `MainControl`, and when using `++` I will need the iterator to point at the next pointer in that array.

I can't understand how this can be done when I don't have access to this array in the methods of the `Iterator` class.

Can someone help out please? Thanks in advance.

I thought about adding in the class `MainControl`:

```
friend class Iterator;
```

But still I don't get any parameter that will indicate which `MainControl` object I am working on, in other examples I saw this parameter received but here this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a plain array, then you can increment the address:

```
Iterator& Iterator::operator++()
{
    ++address;
    return *this;
}
```

You can use the same approach for `operator<`.

If your data structure is more complex, it can indeed be a good idea to define the `Iterator` as a friend class and pass a pointer to `MainControl` to the iterator. In this case, however, this is not necessary.

Unrelated side note: Comparing iterators using `<` is only meaningful for random-access iterators (yours can be a random-access iterator easily, so this is fine). If you simply want to iterate the elements, `!=` is a better choice because it has less assumptions. See [iterator concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) for more details.

Comment: How do you pass the pointer where the the iterator is used the way I wrote in the post? No pointers are passed, and I need that code specifically to run properly.

Comment: As I said: In this case you don't even need this. In other cases, the `.begin()` and `.end()` method of `MainControl` would take care of this.

Comment: I tried implementing it as you suggested but that gives me a run time error.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed this by defining the class Iterator with a pointer to a pointer instead of a pointer.

Comment: This does not sound right. Feel free to edit your question and show your implementation.